# What purpose does [QueryProperty("Name", "name")] serve in a Xamarin Shell app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking at the Xamarin shell samples I see this:

```
namespace Xaminals.Views
{
    [QueryProperty("Name", "name")]
    public partial class CatDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string Name
        {
            set
            {
                BindingContext = CatData.Cats.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
            }
        }

        public CatDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the purpose of:  [QueryProperty("Name", "name")]

Comment: Is this `SearchHandler.QueryProperty`? I don't think so, I have a feeling this is custom attribute!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It allows you to pass parameters to a page when using url navigation

It is discussed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt848639.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

For pages to receive data when navigating, the page class must be decorated with a `QueryPropertyAttribute`.

When you set

```
[QueryProperty("Name", "name")]
```

The first argument - `"Name"` refers to the name of the property that will be receiving the data.

The second argument - `"name"` refers to the parameter `id` that will be passed in the query

You can read more in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation)